# Boost Graph example doesn't compile.

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I took the code from

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/edge_list.html

included my header,

```
#include <iostream>                  // for std::cout
#include <utility>                   // for std::pair
#include <algorithm>                 // for std::for_each
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/edge_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/bellman_ford_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/johnson_all_pairs_shortest.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace boost;
int main(){
      enum { u, v, x, y, z, N };
  char name[] = { 'u', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'z' };

  typedef std::pair<int,int> E;
  E edges[] = { E(u,y), E(u,x), E(u,v),
                E(v,u),
                E(x,y), E(x,v),
                E(y,v), E(y,z),
                E(z,u), E(z,x) };

  int weight[] = { -4, 8, 5,
                   -2,
                   9, -3,
                   7, 2,
                   6, 7 };

  typedef boost::edge_list<E*> Graph;
  Graph g(edges, edges + sizeof(edges) / sizeof(E));

  std::vector<int> distance(N, std::numeric_limits<short>::max());
  std::vector<int> parent(N,-1);

  distance[z] = 0;
  parent[z] = z;
  bool r = boost::bellman_ford_shortest_paths(g, int(N), weight,
                                              distance.begin(),
                                              parent.begin());
  if (r)  
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
      std::cout << name[i] << ": " << distance[i]
                << " " << name[parent[i]] << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "negative cycle" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

compile with

```
g++ -O3 boostexampl.cpp -I/user/include/
```

I got this error

```
make -k 
g++ -O3 boostexampl.cpp -I/user/include/
boostexampl.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
boostexampl.cpp:40:61: error: no matching function for call to ‘bellman_ford_shortest_paths(Graph&, int, int [10], std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator)’
boostexampl.cpp:40:61: note: candidates are:
In file included from boostexampl.cpp:7:0:
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/bellman_ford_shortest_paths.hpp:91:8: note: template<class EdgeListGraph, class Size, class WeightMap, class PredecessorMap, class DistanceMap, class BinaryFunction, class BinaryPredicate, class BellmanFordVisitor> bool boost::bellman_ford_shortest_paths(EdgeListGraph&, Size, WeightMap, PredecessorMap, DistanceMap, BinaryFunction, BinaryPredicate, BellmanFordVisitor)
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/bellman_ford_shortest_paths.hpp:91:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
boostexampl.cpp:40:61: note:   candidate expects 8 arguments, 5 provided
In file included from boostexampl.cpp:7:0:
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/bellman_ford_shortest_paths.hpp:210:8: note: template<class EdgeListGraph, class Size, class P, class T, class R> bool boost::bellman_ford_shortest_paths(EdgeListGraph&, Size, const boost::bgl_named_params<P, T, R>&)
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/bellman_ford_shortest_paths.hpp:210:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
boostexampl.cpp:40:61: note:   mismatched types ‘const boost::bgl_named_params<P, T, R>’ and ‘int [10]’
In file included from boostexampl.cpp:7:0:
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/bellman_ford_shortest_paths.hpp:222:8: note: template<class EdgeListGraph, class Size> bool boost::bellman_ford_shortest_paths(EdgeListGraph&, Size)
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/bellman_ford_shortest_paths.hpp:222:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
boostexampl.cpp:40:61: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 5 provided
In file included from boostexampl.cpp:7:0:
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/bellman_ford_shortest_paths.hpp:229:8: note: template<class VertexAndEdgeListGraph, class P, class T, class R> bool boost::bellman_ford_shortest_paths(VertexAndEdgeListGraph&, const boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base>&)
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/bellman_ford_shortest_paths.hpp:229:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
boostexampl.cpp:40:61: note:   mismatched types ‘const boost::bgl_named_params<T, Tag, Base>’ and ‘int’
make: *** [examp] Error 1
make: Target `main' not remade because of errors.

Compilation exited abnormally with code 2 at Sat Oct  5 14:24:35
```

I am kind of stuck here. Any help would be appreciated. Sorry I provides the full code, but I don't know where is problem is. Is boost examples guaranteed to work? did they change the interface but didn't change on-line example? Or I didn't include headers.

Comment: looks like that your example code was written for another version of `boost::graph`, since the usage doesn't match.

Comment: I have boost1.54 installed. So you are saying the tutorial they give is wrong?

Comment: If you haven't changed the code and it doesn't compile, than it's wrong in some way. Presumably out of date w.r.t. the library.